Is there a shortcut to open vim and then jump to line ”num“ as ":num"?
I used to search words in my code tree by grep -rn. And the output is just as below.
"{filename}:{num}:{line content}"

Sometimes I will to open the file with vim, and jump to the line num as below.
vim {filename} +{num}

But I would like to do those steps as below. Is there any shortcut?
vim {filename}:{num}


Try vim-fetch plugin: https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5089

You can use Vim's built-in :grep command.

Instead of typing vim filename:line manually, you can perform grep and jump within vim. check :h grep. The old Ack plugin is nice too. Additionally, I wrote QFGrep long time ago. It allows you to filter further in the quickfix window. https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep

You could create a shell function to do this, say, vimn:
vimn () {
  case $1 in
  (*:[1-9]*) vim "${1%:*}" +"${1##*:}";;
  (*)        vim "$@"
  esac
}

This assumes a Bourne-type shell (sh, bash, ksh, zsh, ...). There are ways to make this work for a function named vim as well, but I prefer to avoid overloading command names.
EDIT: make this work for vimn hello:world:42 -> open hello:world at line 42.

I like it, it's cool!

The following command re-executes your previous grep commands and redirects its output to a temporary file so that it can be consumed by Vim as a quickfix:
$ vim -q <(!!)

You can then use various quickfix commands to navigate between/operate on the results. See :help quickfix.
If you simply want to open a given file (README.md) in Vim at a given line (7), the syntax is:
$ vim +7 README.md

…as indicated in $ vim --help.
If you absolutely want to use the file:num form, you will have to find a plugin that does that, as Vim itself doesn't.

Should be noted that <(!!) are shell features. In other words: this won't work in cmd (but then again, what does?)

You can create a shell function for your personal syntax:
vimln() {
  local argument="$1"
  IFS=':' read -r filename line_number <<< "$argument"
  vim "+$line_number" "$filename"
}

This function has no validation, but you can add one. It just splits the filename and line number for the vim parameters. So it should work if you type vimln filename.txt:45.
For an alternative way, you can also use vim -c <command> for execute <command> after loading the file like vim -c "10" filename.txt or vim +15 filename.txt -c 'normal zt' if you want to execute a command in normal mode.
